# Missing Values in a Time Period Difference Measurement

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, nan, missing-data

I have some time stamp data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'t' : [dt.datetime(2016,1,7),float('NaN'),dt.datetime(2016,1,8),float('NaN')],
                   'A' : [0,1,1,1]})
```

[image]

Some of my t values are NaT. I would like to change A to make it zero on rows with a NaT please, like this:

[image]

I tried:

```
# Missing values of time
def MVOT(t,A):
    if math.isnan(t):
        return 0
    else:
        return A
MVOT = np.vectorize(MVOT,otypes=[float])
df["A"] = MVOT(df['t'],df['A'])
```

but I got:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the time to a number

```
df['t'] = pd.to_numeric(df.t)
```

the NaT values are converted to negative numbers so:

```
df.loc[df.t < 0,'A'] = 0
```

[image]